# Why is my binary to decimal program giving incorrect outputs?

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I'm working on this program that takes a binary string and converts it to decimal, using [this guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Binary-to-Decimal) to convert from binary to decimal. When I run through the for loop in my head, I get what the correct outputs would be. And yet, when I run my program, I get this strange output:

```
1
3
7
15
31
63
127
```

The actual output should look like this:

```
1
2
5
11
22
44
89
```

I cannot figure this out for the life of me. Why is my program doing this? Here's the current source code:

```
public class BinaryToDecimal
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String binary = "1011001";
    int toMultiplyBy;
    int decimalValue = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= binary.length(); i++)
    {
        int whatNumber = binary.indexOf(i);
        if (whatNumber == 0)
        {
            toMultiplyBy = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            toMultiplyBy = 1;
        }
        decimalValue = ((decimalValue * 2) + toMultiplyBy);
        System.out.println(decimalValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Welcome to SO.  Congratulations on writing a model example of how questions should look here.

Comment: 1) I think "indexOf()" might have an "off-by-one" error, 2) I honestly don't see where you're shifting to the current power-of-two and 3) yes, "`parseInt(str, 2)`" is light years simpler and more efficient :)

Comment: It's a class assignment, so unfortunately I'm not allowed to use partInt(). If only, it would make my life way easier...

Comment: Strings are 0 based so you should loop through the String from 0, but indexOf, is not what you want to use. You want to use `charAt(...)` or `subString(...)` and then parse to int. I would use `charAt(...) - '0'` myself.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are 0 based so you should loop through the String from 0 to < the String's length, but `indexOf(...)`, is not what you want to use since this will search for the location in the String of small ints which makes no sense. You don't care where the char equivalent of 2 is located in the String or even if it is in the String at all.

Instead you want to use `charAt(...)` or `subString(...)` and then parse to int. I would use

```
for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
    int whatNumber = charAt(i) - '0'; // converts a numeric char into it's int
    //...
```

To see what this is doing, create and run:

```
public class CheckChars {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String foo = "0123456789";

      for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); i++) {
         char myChar = foo.charAt(i);
         int actualIntHeld = (int) myChar;
         int numberIWant = actualIntHeld - '0';

         System.out.printf("'%s' - '0' is the same as %d - %d = %d%n", 
               myChar, actualIntHeld, (int)'0', numberIWant);
      }
   }
}
```

Which returns:

```
'0' - '0' is the same as 48 - 48 = 0
'1' - '0' is the same as 49 - 48 = 1
'2' - '0' is the same as 50 - 48 = 2
'3' - '0' is the same as 51 - 48 = 3
'4' - '0' is the same as 52 - 48 = 4
'5' - '0' is the same as 53 - 48 = 5
'6' - '0' is the same as 54 - 48 = 6
'7' - '0' is the same as 55 - 48 = 7
'8' - '0' is the same as 56 - 48 = 8
'9' - '0' is the same as 57 - 48 = 9
```

The numbers that represent the chars is based on the old ASCII table that gave each symbol a numeric representation. For more on this, please look here: [ASCII Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Comment: It works! Awesome, thanks a bunch! I just have one question, if you don't mind - when I fired tried substituting `indexOf(i)` for `charAt(i)`, it didn't work. Then when I tried `charAt(i) - '0'` it worked. Why does adding the `'0'` suddenly give it the proper output?

Comment: @Kyle: create a small program and see what the int equivalent of '0' is. It's not 0, but an almost arbitrary number that has been decided long ago will represent the '0' character. The '1' char is 1 greater than this, and '2' is 2 greater than '0', so if you normalize the int by subtracting out the '0', you'll get the int value for the number that the char represents.

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

1. Array indexing starts at zero, not 1, so your loop should be `for (int i=0; i

   You are confusing `indexOf()` with `substring()`.  In your case, `binary.indexOf(i)` does the following.  First, the integer `i` is converted to a string. Then `binary` is searched left-to-right for a substring matching the string value of `i`.  The first time through the loop `i==1`.  This returns zero, because there's a `1` at index zero in `binary`.  The second time, the value of `i` is `2`.  There's no `2` in `binary`, so this returns zero.  For `i==3`, you're looking for a string `3` in `binary`, which will never be true.

Take a look at the `String#substring()` method, which is what I believe you intended.